# Why does conditional assignment not occur in data table join using binary search?

Tags: r, data.table

I want to assign to a column of a data table if some condition holds true. It occurs when using vector scan but not when using binary search. Could you explain the cause of this?

```
dt['1291703']$test = 'ali'
# Error in `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, "1291703", value = list(filename =
# "1291703",  :         i[1] is NA. Can't assign by reference to row 'NA'.

dt[cik=='1291703']$test = 'ali'
dt[cik=='1291703']
##                filename     cik signatureDate test
## 1: 0000919574-09-007207 1291703    2009-03-12  ali
## 2: 0000919574-09-007310 1291703    2009-03-19  ali
```

Answer (score 0):

Without additional information, it seems that the problem with your binary search attempt is that you are trying to assign `ali` to `temp` column on row number `1291703`, which probably doesn't exist.

In binary search, you should first of all remember to key your data set by the column you want to search in. The second thing to understand is, that when you are passing an integer to `i`, it is searching for that row number by default, thus you should use `J()` (or `.()` in version 1.9.4+) instead.

You should also use `:=` instead of `$` in order to assign by reference. Thus the solution should look something like this:

```
setkey(dt, cik)[J(1291703), test := 'ali']
dt
#                filename     cik signatureDate test
# 1: 0000919574-09-007207 1291703    2009-03-12  ali
# 2: 0000919574-09-007310 1291703    2009-03-19  ali
```

If `cik` is of class `character` (which is unclear from your question), the following should also work

```
dt[, test := NULL] # Removing `test` for illustration
dt[, cik := as.character(cik)] # Converting `cik` to class `character`, also for illustration
setkey(dt, cik)['1291703', test := 'ali'] # Implementing binary search without using `J()`
dt
#                filename     cik signatureDate test
# 1: 0000919574-09-007207 1291703    2009-03-12  ali
# 2: 0000919574-09-007310 1291703    2009-03-19  ali
```